# how to detect corner in a digital image using MATLAB?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, image-segmentation, matlab-cvst

I am designing an algorithm for image processing. I am using MATLAB for the processing of the images(video). How I can detect the position of the corners in the image?

Comment: You realize that the first result google finds for "matlab corner detection" is a command called `corner`?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of video, the best approach to use is the [ShiTomasi](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30822-lucas-kanade-tracker-with-pyramid-and-iteration/content//LK%20Tracker/corner_ST.m) Corner Detector. (`detectMinEigenFeatures`). Now, if you want to detect corners that contains some invariant featrues, you should use `SURF`, `BRISK`, `ORG`, `AKAZE`, `FREAK`, etc...

Example:

```
im = rgb2gray(imread('image.jpg'));
[r c] = corner_ST(im,20);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function `corner` in the Image Processing Toolbox.  There are several functions for detecting different types of corners in the Computer Vision System Toolbox: `detectHarrisFeatures`, `detectMinEigenFeatures`, and `detectFASTFeatures`.